# Getting error while trying to use mainClassName

Tags: android, api, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html) SMS service but while setting the SMSBackend class I am not able to set the mainClassName due to which I am not able to get the link as given in the blog for last few hr I am stuck at this I have tried the jar method, only class name, full class name here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories { jcenter() }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'


android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.iquesoft.smsapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
mainClassName = 'net.iquesoft.smsapp.SMSBackend'

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.6.0'
implementation group: 'com.twilio.sdk', name: 'twilio', version: '7.9.0'
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and i am getting error like this
`Could not set unknown property 'mainClassName' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an Android project to generate the Backend.

You have to create a Java project with the Spark framework as he said [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/getting-started-with-gradle-and-the-spark-framework-3.html) and when you have your Backend running you can create your Android project.

Comment: Bro i tried but not able to get any message i even set the twilio no also